# Algorithm for minimum manhattan distance

Tags: algorithm

I wish to find the point with the minimum sum of manhattan distance/rectilinear distance from a set of points (i.e the sum of rectilinear distance between this point and each point in the set should be minimum ). The resulting point can be one of the points from the given set (not necessarily). In case more than one points exist with the same minimum distance, i wish to retrieve all of them.

IN OTHER WORDS:

I have a grid with certain intersections marked. I'd like to find the intersection that is closest to all the marked intersections. That is, I need to find a point such that the sum of distances from all points is minimum.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, we should add that tag. Also, are you given a list of points to choose the answer from?

Comment: means you have a grid and some point on it marked and you want find a point in grid which has minimum average Manhattan distance with marked point?

Comment: What is your problem then? This is not a real question, I think.

Comment: Are you asking: I have a grid with certain intersections marked. I'd like to find an intersection on the grid that is closest to all of the marked intersections. ??

Comment: Not a homework, i came across the article http://www.springerlink.com/content/2yrp1u5gkdf05pgx/ , but i couldn't understand a single word, thought someone could explain in here in simple english.

Comment: @JonathanM yes, i need to find a point such that the sum of distances from all points is minimum.

Comment: This is a classic problem. See the girlfriend problem in Martin Gardner's book "Aha! Insight."

Comment: @TylerDurden Is the solution proposed there similar to what I have? Maybe if not, it will be a good idea that you add another answer for reference. If you do so, please @ me so that I receive a notification :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The cool thing about the Manhatan distance is that the distance itself comprises of two independent components: the distance on the x and y coordinate. Thus you can solve two simpler tasks and merge the results from them to obtain the desired results.

The task I speak of is: given are points on a line. Find the point on the line that minimizes the sum of the absolute distances to all the points. If there are many find all of them (btw they always turn to be a single segment which is easy to prove). The segment is determined by the (potentially two) points medians of the set. By median I mean the point that has equal number of points to the left and to the right of it. In case the number of points is even there is no such point and you choose the points with difference 1 in both directions to form the segment.

Here I add examples of solutions of this simpler task:

In case the points on the line are like that:

```
-4 | | | 0 | 2 3 4
             ^
```

The solution is just a point and it is `2`.

In case the points on the line are like that:

```
-4 | | | 0 | 2 3
         ^---^
```

The whole segment [0, 2] is the solution of the problem.

You solve this task separately for the `x` and `y` coordinate and then merge the results to obtain the rectangle of minimum distanced points.

---

#### EXAMPLE

And now comes an example of the solution for the initial task.

Imagine you want to find the points that are with minimum Manhatan distance to the set `(0, 6), (1, 3), (3, 5), (3, 3), (4, 7), (2, 4)`

You form the two simpler tasks:

For x:

```
0 1 2 3 3 4
    ^-^
```

And here the solution is the segment `[2, 3]` (note that here we have duplicated point `3`, which I represented in probably not the most intuitive way).

For y:

```
3 3 4 5 6 7
    ^-^
```

Here the solution is the segment `[4, 5]`.

Finally we get that the solution of the initial task is the rectangle with formula:

```
 2 <= x <= 3; 4 <= y <= 5
```

---

#### COMPLEXITY

As many people show interest in this post I decided to improve it a bit more.

Let's speak about complexity.

The complexity of the task is actually the same as the complexity of solving the simpler task (because as already discussed the solution actually consists of solving two simpler tasks). Many people will go and solve it via sorting and then choosing out the medians. However, this will cause `O(nlog n)` complexity, where `n` is the number of points in the input set.

This can be improved if a better algorithm for finding the kth element is used ([Example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/) of implementation in the C++ STL). This algorithm basically follows the same approach as qsort. The running time is `O(n)`. Even in the case of two median points this will still remain linear (needing two runs of the same algorithm), and thus the total complexity of the algorithm becomes `O(n)`. It is obvious that the task can not be solved any faster, as long as the input itself is of the mentioned complexity.

Comment: Could you explain with this example, say the set is {(1,1) (2,2)}, thus the points with minimum sum of manhattan distance would be {(1,1), (2,2), (1,2), (2,1)}, for each one of them the sum being 2.

Comment: @user1045047 I am still improving my post. Now I added a complete example on how you find the solutions of the original task too.

Comment: Why is median a solution for the problem?

Comment: The running time is not O(n), but O(n) on average;)

Comment: @BorisStrandjev Do all points in the rectangle belong to the solution set? That is, are all Manhattan distances from those points to N given points equal? Thank you very much.

Comment: @dh16 The SUM of Manhatan distances to all the points in the tatgetted set is equal for all points in the solution i find. Still, of course, the Manhatan distances to a single point of the targetted set might change when choosing different points of the rectangle.

Comment: @milo You can read more about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median

Comment: Thank you very much, this concept helped me for a problem today. Pretty new for me concept but made that problem easy with this concept