# Two player grid traversal game

Tags: java, algorithm, math, dynamic-programming, greedy

Given a `M * N` grid and location of two players `p1` and `p2`on grid. There are n balls placed on different positions on the grid. Let the location of these balls be `B(1), B(2), B(3) ..., B(n)`.

We need to calculate the **minumum manhattan distance** required to pick all the balls. Balls should be picked in ascending order i.e if `B(i)` is picked before `B(j)` if `i < j`. 

Consider the following sample case:

`p1 = (1, 1)
 p2 = (3, 4)`
Lets consider location of balls as 
`B(1) = (1, 1), B(2) = (2, 1), B(3) = (3, 1), B(4) = (5, 5)`
**Output** will be `5` because `p1` will first choose `B(1), B(2), B(3)` and `p1` will choose `B(4)`

**My Approach**

 I did a **greedy** **approach** and calculated distance of `p1` and `p2` from a given ball `B(i)` (starting from `i = 1 to n`) and added the minimum to the output and updated the position of the player accordingly.
 But this approach fails for a lot of testcases. 

P.S: This question was asked in one of my past interviews and `O(n)` solution to this problem is expected.

Edit: More testcases can be like
 `p1 = (1,1) p2 = (3,5)`

`B(1) = (3, 3), B(2) = (1, 1), B(3) = (4, 5), B(4) = (2, 1), B(5) = (4, 3).` 
In this case `p1` will choose `B(2), B(4)`
and `p2` will choose `B(1), B(3), B(5)`

**Output** will be 8.

`p1 = (1,1) p2 = (3,4)`

`B(1) = (2, 2), B(2) = (3, 2), B(3) = (4, 2), B(4) = (1, 1)`
In this case `p1` will choose `B(4)`
and `p2` will choose `B(1), B(2), B(3)`

**Output** will be 5.

Note: **When player chooses a ball he moves to that point**.

P.P.S. After discussion I believe **no linear-time solution exists** to this problem and **O(n^2) solution** is the best solution available.

Comment: Maybe you should  take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402087/algorithm-for-minimum-manhattan-distance).

Comment: I gave a look to this. I think that the two questions are different because in this question we are trying to divide the set of points into two different sets such that distance of element in one set is distant from element in another set @theVoid

Comment: I didn't suggest a duplicate here, i just provided you with a link that i thought could be proven useful to you.

Comment: Can you show some of the failed test cases ?

Comment: @Nelxiost i provided with one failed testcase

Comment: @NikhilPathania I don't see how your approach fails on this one. To me, it produces the desired output, 8.

Comment: @Nelxiost i have updated, this one is failing

Comment: I also doubt that a linear time solution exists that is *guaranteed* to find the optimal solution. But I'll think a bit more about this.

Comment: It seems linear time solution might not exist, since simply to know all the distances between balls is O(N^2)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **O(n^3)** solution where we either choose `balls[i]` from `p1` or `p2`

```
let memo = {};

function findMinDistance (p1, p2, balls, n) {
    if (n === balls.length) return 0;
    const key = `${n}_${p1}_${p2}`;
    
    function dis (a, b) {
    return Math.abs(a[0] - b[0]) + Math.abs(a[1] - b[1]);
    }
    
   if (memo[key]) {
       return memo[key]
   }
    
    const minDis = Math.min(
        dis(p1, balls[n]) + findMinDis (balls[n], p2, balls, n + 1),
        dis(p2, balls[n]) + findMinDis (p1, balls[n], balls, n + 1)
    );
    
    memo[key] = minDis;
    return minDis
}


function solve() {
    let p1 = [1,1];
    let p2 = [3,4];
    let balls = [ [2,2], [3,2], [4,2], [1,1] ];
    
    console.log(findMinDis(p1, p2, balls, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a linear-time algorithm. But here is a n² dynamic program:

For every point in time (i.e. for every ball), you can choose either of the players to pick up the ball. An interesting information we should maintain is the position of the other player at this time. So our state for time `Ti` consists of either of `{P1, P2}` and the location of the other player. Now, we want to incrementally calculate the minimum distance for every point in time and every possible state by computing the following table (using your first example):

```
             T1   T2   T3   T4
----------+--------------------
P1; P2@p2 |  0
P1; P2@B1 |
P1; P2@B2 |
P1; P2@B3 |
P2; P1@p1 |  5
P2; P1@B1 |
P2; P1@B2 |
P2; P1@B3 |
```

The two initial values are the distances between `p1` and `B1` and `p2` and `B1`, respectively.

From every state, we can go directly to the right neighboring cell. This equals moving the according player to the new ball and keeping the other player at its current location. The change in cost is the distance between the current ball and the new ball.

And for every new column, we have a new entry at the end (for both players). This means that the other player picked up the last ball and the current player could be anywhere. So we have to find the minimum distance of all possible locations of the current player to the current ball. I'll give a visualization of this at the end of this post. This way, we can fill the entire table column by column:

Example (again from your question)

```
p1 = (1, 1)
p2 = (3, 4) 
B(1) = (1, 1)
B(2) = (2, 1)
B(3) = (3, 1)
B(4) = (5, 5)
```

DP table:

```
             T1   T2            T3               T4
----------+---------------------------------------------------------
P1; P2@p2 |  0    0+1=2         1+1=2            2+6=8
P1; P2@B1 |       min(5+1)=6    6+1=7            7+6=13
P1; P2@B2 |                     min(6+2,4+2)=6   6+6=12
P1; P2@B3 |                                      min(7+8,5+8,4+7)=11
P2; P1@p1 |  5   5+1=6          6+1=7            7+6=13
P2; P1@B1 |      min(0+4)=4     4+1=5            5+6=11
P2; P1@B2 |                     min(1+3,6+2)=4   4+6=10
P2; P1@B3 |                                      min(2+3,7+8,6+7)=5
```

The minimum in the last column is **5** (i.e. the minimum distance to collect all balls is 5). Tracing back, we get: P2@B4, P1@B3, P1@B2, P1@B1.

Here is the promised visualization. The diagonal dependencies for the last column have been omitted for reasons of clarity:

[image]

I won't provide pseudo-code since it is very likely that I would mix up some indexing (leading to more confusion than help). But you should be able to write the code from the description above.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but as i mentioned a linear time solution was expected by me during interview @Nico Schertler

Comment: Yes, I know. Right now, I do not believe that a linear time algorithm exists. But I would be glad to stand corrected. If it exists, then it is probably a variation of this DP. That's why I posted the answer. Possible improvements may regard the Manhattan distance (it is separable along the axes, but I do not see how that would help) or the sparse connectivity of the table cells.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of an `O(n^2)` dynamic programming, similar to Nico's answer. The idea of the function is:

```
// Given N positions, return total distance after a move to B(n),
// where p is the position of the player not at B(n-1)
f(n,p): 

  // at the end, choose between player on prev B and the other
  if n == N-1:
    return min(d(p,B[n]), d(B[n-1],B[n]))

  // otherwise,
  return min(
      // either move player from previous B
      d(B[n-1],B[n]) + f(n+1,p),

      // or move player from other location, p
      d(p,B[n]) + f(n+1,B[n-1])
  )
```

JavaScript code, filling the matrix from the end to the beginning. Once completed, we choose between starting with one player or the other, `M[0][N]` or `M[0][N+1]`:

```js
// Manhattan distance
function d(a,b){
  return Math.abs(a[0] - b[0]) + Math.abs(a[1] - b[1]);
}

var B = [[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[5,5]], p1 = [1,1], p2 = [3,4];
var N = B.length;

// append initial player positions to B
B.push(p1);
B.push(p2);

// create matrix M[i][j]
// i = current B, j = index of location for player not on B[i-1]
var M = new Array(N);
for (var i=0; i<N; i++){
  M[i] = new Array(N + 2);
}

// at the last B, choose between player on prev B and the other
for (var p=0; p<N+2; p++){
  M[N-1][p] = Math.min(d(B[p],B[N-1]), d(B[N-2],B[N-1]));
}

// either move player from prev B, or from other position, p
for (var i=N-2; i>0; i--){
  for (var p=0; p<N+2; p++){
    M[i][p] = Math.min(d(B[i-1],B[i]) + M[i+1][p],
                       d(B[p],B[i]) + M[i+1][i-1]);
  }
}

// on the first B, choose between the first and second players
M[0][N] = d(B[N],B[0]) + M[1][N+1];
M[0][N+1] = d(B[N+1],B[0]) + M[1][N];

for (var i=0; i<N; i++)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(M[i]));
```